# Language C formatted string without printf

Tags: c, string

that is what I want:

```
char *getHour(){
return ("%d:%d:%d",hour, min, sec);
}
```

Return a string like this "hh:mm:ss"
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why do you want to avoid printf?  (I assume you mean sprintf in this context...)

Comment: Have a look at `sprintf()` and/or `strftime()` in your C documentation.

Comment: My [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555406/how-to-compare-two-time-stamp-in-format-month-date-hhmmss-to-check-ve-or-v/15556395#15556395) will help you, but I think @pmg is more close to your answer.

Comment: hour, min and sec are int value. when i call getHour, i just want those value formatted as showed

Comment: Building the formatted string is one part of the problem. Returning it to the caller is another. For the latter, see questions 7.5a and 7.5b of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: `asprintf` is pretty cool, if all the systems your code needs to run on support it. (also, `%02d` in your format string)

Answer (score 2):

One potential implementation is as shown below

**EDIT:** Incorporating Dave's suggestions on `static` array, `snprintf` and returning a `const char *`

```
int hh = 5, mm = 45, ss = 20;

const char* getHour()
{
    static char hourStr[32];
    snprintf(hourStr,14, "%d:%d:%d\n", hh, mm, ss);
    return hourStr;
}
```

If you print the output of this implementation as `printf("GetHour: %s\n", getHour());`, you would get `GetHour: 5:45:20` which I presume is your expected output.

Comment: the internal buffer is a nice idea, but you should make it `static` rather than a global, and make the function return `const char*` to emphasise that the memory is managed internally. Passing the parameters as globals is a bad idea. Finally you should use `snprintf` to avoid overflows (not an issue with such a huge buffer and at most 3 ints, but a good practice nonetheless)

Comment: @Dave A wonderful comment. Though I am not an exponent of `globals` myself, I used it to show the print. Point about `snprintf` is very apt.

Answer (score 0):

You can return one only string, concat hour, min and sec like:

str = hour + min + sec

to do this use the function strcat(destination, source) (#include)
the will apear like that:

```
char *getHour(....)

{

char str[20];

strcpy(str,hour);

strcat(str,":");

strcat(str,min);

strcat(str,":");

strcat(str,"sec);

return str;

}
```

Comment: repeated `strcat` is expensive. It's better to use proper tools like `sprintf` or `strftime`.

Comment: @Jim Balter -- you might be surprised.  strcpy and strcat on modern CPUs are very fast, whereas the parsing that sprintf has to do makes it expensive also.  In my timing tests, the above example is considerably faster than sprintf("%s:%s:%s",hour,min,sec) -- more than a factor of two (gcc 4.7, Win 7, core i5-670 CPU).  While I understand that for longer strings this might change, it's always worth some timing tests if you're interested in the last ounce of performance.

Comment: @willus My comment wasn't about the cost of an individual strcat; repeated strcat is O(N^2). And in general terms it's better to use the proper tools ... only do timing tests for demonstrated bottlenecks.

Comment: @Jim Balter -- Ah. *In general*, you say.  The fact remains that in *this case*, your original comment is quite misleading.  Four calls to strcat (which is typically in-lined and uses built-in CPU opcodes) on short strings far outperform a single sprintf or strftime call.  And I disagree about using timing tests.  If you want to write highly optimized performance code, you need to know what CPUs and compilers do well.  A simple way to find that out is with timing comparisons.

Comment: @willus I don't believe that my comment was misleading and I'm not concerned with whether some random person disagrees with me.

Comment: @João Paulo Moro Loureiro -- The most significant issue with your function as it stands now is that you return a pointer to a local character array--an array which is not guaranteed to exist anymore after the function completes.  You need to minimally make the declaration of str[] to be static:  static char str[20];

Answer (score 0):

I'll pretend you have a good reason for doing this. Here's the code you're looking for:

```
char *getHourMinuteSecond( int hour, int minute, int second ) {
    assert( hour >= 0 && hour < 24 );
    assert( minute >= 0 && minute < 60 );
    assert( second >= 0 && second <= 60 ); // leap seconds... maybe

    char *output = (char *) malloc( 9 * sizeof( char ) );
    if( output == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    output[0] = (char) ((hour / 10) + '0');
    output[1] = (char) ((hour % 10) + '0');
    output[2] = ':';
    output[3] = (char) ((minute / 10) + '0');
    output[4] = (char) ((minute % 10) + '0');
    output[5] = ':';
    output[6] = (char) ((second / 10) + '0');
    output[7] = (char) ((second % 10) + '0');
    output[8] = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

Now lets relax the restriction to something a little saner. We can use snprintf:

```
char *getHourMinuteSecond( int hour, int minute, int second ) {
    assert( hour >= 0 && hour < 24 );
    assert( minute >= 0 && minute < 60 );
    assert( second >= 0 && second <= 60 ); // leap seconds... maybe

    char *output = (char *) malloc( 9 * sizeof( char ) );
    if( output == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    snprintf( output, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second );
    return output;
}
```

Lets get saner still, and have the function return via a parameter (so that we don't need to play with `malloc`):

```
void getHourMinuteSecond( char target[9], int hour, int minute, int second ) {
    assert( target != NULL );
    assert( hour >= 0 && hour < 24 );
    assert( minute >= 0 && minute < 60 );
    assert( second >= 0 && second <= 60 ); // leap seconds... maybe

    snprintf( target, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second );
}
```

Hang on, that last function was mostly error checking. We can get silly again and use a `#define`:

```
#define getHourMinuteSecond(tgt,h,m,s) snprintf(tgt,9,"%02d:%02d:%02d",h,m,s)
```

Finally, in your original code, you don't take `hour`, `minute` or `second` as parameters, so maybe you want the function to determine them?

```
void getHourMinuteSecond( char target[9] ) {
    assert( target != NULL );
    const time_t now = time( 0 );
    const tm *const tmnow = localtime( &now );
    snprintf( target, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", tmnow->tm_hour, tmnow->tm_min, tmnow->tm_sec );
}
```