# C equivalent of PHP `date('YmdHis')`

Tags: php, c

couldn't find an answer on google.

Is there an equivalent in C for PHP `date('YmdHis')` output:

`20130613153516`

Thank you!

Comment: What do u exactly want ? the same output as u have given in C ?

Comment: try as suggested in below answer... look about strftime().....http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: this may help you: [How to compare two time stamp in format “Month Date hh:mm:ss” to check +ve or -ve value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555406/how-to-compare-two-time-stamp-in-format-month-date-hhmmss-to-check-ve-or-v/15556395#15556395)

Comment: [C date and time functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions) and [C++ Date and Time](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strftime` function in `c` to achive same functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t x;
    time(&x);
    struct tm *tmptr = localtime(&x);
    char buf[1000];

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m%d%I%M%S", tmptr);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is like:

```
20130613051142
```

Based on my local time ofcourse.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 1024

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char buffer[MAX];
    time_t t;

    t = time(NULL);

    strftime(buffer, MAX, "%Y%m%d%I%M%S", localtime(&t));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```