# Compare sytem time with variables - C++

Tags: c++, string, date

I'm having trouble comparing two dates.

First i set my variables to comparation:

```
string StartTime = "0800", EndTime = "2000";
```

Now i storage hour and minute of Windows system in "SystemTime":

```
auto t = std::time(nullptr);
auto SystemTime = std::put_time(localtime(&t), "%H%M"); //Output example: 0700
```

Finally, I try to compare the times:

```
 if (SystemTime < StartTime || SystemTime > EndTime)
  cout << SystemTime << endl;
```

I don't have much experience with C ++. But why can't I compare these two strings? How can i solve it?

Thanks for atention!

Comment: Please update your question with the error(s) you're getting along with your expected output.

Comment: "..why can't I compare these two strings.." This itself is wrong. You are not comparing two strings. The type of *StartTime* is string but that the type of *SystemTime* is not string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two time stamp in format "Month Date hh:mm:ss" to check +ve or -ve value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555406/how-to-compare-two-time-stamp-in-format-month-date-hhmmss-to-check-ve-or-v)

Answer (score 0):

The type of *StartTime* and *EndTime* is string, whereas the type of value returned by std::put_time is not a string hence you cannot directly compare these two unless you have some comparison operator overloads to do that.

Ideally you should convert the StartTime and EndTime in std::time type and then compare with the SystemTime obtained from localtime.

Here you want to convert system time into string, so you need to put the results of put_time into string :

```
...
string SystemTime;
stringstream sysTime(systemTime);

sysTime << std::put_time(localtime(&t), "%H%M"); //Output example: 0700
...
```

Again note that comparing std::time objects is better than converting time to string and then comparing string, as this is error prone e.g. you need to take care of locales etc.