# Find the difference between two dates in hours?

Tags: c

For example I can calculate the difference of these two dates by looking at them but i have no clue when it comes to calculating this in a program.

Dates: A is `2014/02/12(y/m/d) 13:26:33` and B  is `2014/02/14(y/m/d) 11:35:06` then difference in hours is 46.

Comment: Are you getting input like that as a string?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have you checked that question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932909/difference-between-two-dates-in-c

Comment: Read [How to compare two time stamp in format “Month Date hh:mm:ss” to check +ve or -ve value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556395/1673391)

Comment: Typically, you [find the difference in seconds](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) and divide by 60. Different platforms provide different tools for date calculations, so look at the docs for your system.

Comment: when it comes to difftime, how do I use it for months, days, hours, and minutes instead of process time for a program?

Comment: @user3324783 From your comment I think the question marked duplicate to your question is wrong! So I suggest you improve your question, explain correctly what does you want and what did you tried then flag to reopen.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: chasing the Archaeologist badge? I'm not sure if you can get more than one :)

Comment: @chqrlie only [one for each](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist) possible.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: indeed, only 2125 of us :)

Answer (score 6):

I assume your stores time as strings: as `"2014/02/12 13:26:33"`

To calculate time difference you need to use: [`double difftime( time_t time_end, time_t time_beg);`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fdifftim.htm)

the function `difftime()` computes difference between two calendar times as `time_t` objects (`time_end - time_beg`) in seconds. If `time_end` refers to time point before `time_beg` then the result is negative. Now the problem is `difftime()` doesn't accepts strings. We can convert string into [`time_t`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Calendar-Time.html) structure defined in [`time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) in two steps as I also described in my answer: [How to compare two time stamp in format “Month Date hh:mm:ss”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555406/how-to-compare-two-time-stamp-in-format-month-date-hhmmss-to-check-ve-or-v/15556395#15556395):

1. Use [`char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rtref/strpti.htm)  to convert `char*` time string into [`struct tm`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html).

   > The `strptime()` function converts the character string pointed to by buf to values that are stored in the tm structure pointed to by tm, using the format specified by format. To use it you have to using format string specified in documentation:

   For your time format I am explaining  format strings:

   1. %Y: 4-digit year. Can be negative.
   2. %m: Month [1-12]
   3. %d: Day of the month [1–31]
   4. %T: 24 hour time format with seconds, same as %H:%M:%S (you can also use %H:%M:%S explicitly)

   So function call will be as follows:

   ```
   //          Y   M  D  H  M  S 
   strptime("2014/02/12 13:26:33", "%Y/%m/%d %T", &tmi)
   ```

   Where `tmi` is a `struct tm` structure.
2. Step two would be to use: [`time_t mktime(struct tm *time);`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fmktime.htm)

Below is the code I have written(read comments):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE //to remove warning: implicit declaration of ‘strptime’
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    char* time1 = "2014/02/12 13:26:33"; // end
    char* time2 = "2014/02/14 11:35:06"; // beg
    struct tm tm1, tm2; // intermediate datastructes 
    time_t t1, t2; // used in difftime

    //(1) convert `String to tm`:  (note: %T same as %H:%M:%S)  
    if(strptime(time1, "%Y/%m/%d %T", &tm1) == NULL)
       printf("\nstrptime failed-1\n");          
    if(strptime(time2, "%Y/%m/%d %T", &tm2) == NULL)
       printf("\nstrptime failed-2\n");

    //(2) convert `tm to time_t`:    
    t1 = mktime(&tm1);   
    t2 = mktime(&tm2);  
    //(3) Convert Seconds into hours
    double hours = difftime(t2, t1)/60/60;
    printf("%lf\n", hours);
    // printf("%d\n", (int)hours); // to display 46 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall  time_diff.c 
$ ./a.out 
46.142500
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [difftime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) to calculate difference between two times in `C`. However it uses `mktime` and `tm`.

```
double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy (not to talk about timezones) approach is to convert both dates (datetimes) to secounds since 1/1/1970. the build the difference and (tada) devide by 3600

mktime() should do the work, if I remeber correctly

HTH