# HP LoadRunner - Difference between 2 dates in Days

Tags: loadrunner

How does one Calculate the number of Days between 2 dates in HP LoadRunner.

I have limited experience with C language coding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932909/difference-between-two-dates-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are feeling adventurous you can do this:

```
web_js_run(
    "Code=days_between=function(firstDate,secondDate) {return Math.floor((Date.parse(secondDate)-Date.parse(firstDate))/1000/60/60/24);}",
    LAST);

lr_save_string("11/20/2017 23:41:20","D1");
lr_save_string("12/01/2017 02:56:32","D2");

web_js_run(
    "Code=days_between(LR.getParam('D1'),LR.getParam('D2'));",
    "ResultParam=days_between",
    LAST);
```